# Older Nvidia integrated graphics problem

Tags: integrated

I have installed Ubuntu 8.04 right now. 
But I tried to install 12.04 and my graphic doesn't work correctly. 
I have nvidia integrated graphic on MB: MS 7309. Which version of Ubuntu should I use, my processor is amd 3000+ and I have 2 gb ddr2 ram?

Comment: `MS 7309` ist the name of your mainboard? Please give the name of the GPU on your board.

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce 6100 chipset

Comment: Does anybody know how to fix my problem?

Comment: Did the solution below work?

Comment: I will try in a few days, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the nvidia kernel modules. Therefore you have to add an ppa and install the sofware:

- To add the ppa, open a terminal and enter: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates; sudo apt-get update`
- Then you install the software: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current  nvidia-settings`
- Reboot